# Layout params of inflated view are ignored

Tags: android, layout, view, inflate

I inflated a view and added it to my layout :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_add,null,false);

DyL.addView(vi);
```

and I want to change the view parameter dynamically (height) but `getLayoutParams` doesn't work, I always have a null result .So how can I do this? I tried all the solutions I found on the net with no success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

try to set the parent view,

```
View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_add, DyL, false);
```

where DyL is you parent view

Comment: and i can use the layout params normally?

Answer (score -4):

Use your parent view in argument when doesn't require `parent.add(vi)`

```
View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_add, parent , false);
```

Comment: What's the point of answering a 9 days old question when your answer is basically identical to a previous posted answer?

Comment: u always decreses my point mr. L i m new in android i didnt see upper ans